# delete all files except a pattern list file

Tags: linux, bash, rm

I need to delete all the files in the current directory except a list of patterns that are described in a whitelist file (*delete_whitelist.txt*) like this:

```
(.*)dir1(/)?
(.*)dir2(/)?
(.*)dir2/ser1(/)?(.*)
(.*)dir2/ser2(/)?(.*)
(.*)dir2/ser3(/)?(.*)
(.*)dir2/ser4(/)?(.*)
(.*)dir2/ser5(/)?(.*)
```

How can I perform this in one bash line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any bash script can fit on one line:

```bash
find . -type f -print0 | grep -EzZvf delete_whitelist.txt | xargs -0 printf '%s\n'
```

Check the output and then, if it's OK:

```bash
find . -type f -print0 | grep -EzZvf delete_whitelist.txt | xargs -0 rm
```